# make onmouseenter and onmouseleave to work in chrome - html, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, mouseevent

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 50px; top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 150px; background: #222222;" onmouseenter="this.style.background='#aaaaaa'" onmouseleave="this.style.background='#222222';"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/1/

onmouseenter and onmouseleave events works normally in Firefox and Opera, but apparently doesn't work at all in Chrome...

How can a simple basic div like in this fiddle become normally functional in Chrome, but **without changing it's content** (beside assigning a class)?

The ideal solution, if possible, would be to somehow register onmouseenter and onmouseleave events for Chrome users, without assigning a class.

**edit:** I know for onmouseover and onmouseout, but they are out of question - I need some workaround for the code I have for some practical reasons.

**edit 2:** Right now I only have a jquery for specific class - [**http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/6/**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/6/). But I have a LOT of divs with it's events already written in html, inside of `<div></div>`

So for example, I have 2 divs like these (http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/8/). imagine there are 200 divs instead and with a lot more variety in events. How can this be handled to work in Chrome with jquery in the most practical way? (definitely not erasing content from 200 divs and writing jquery with 200 or more lines)

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on chrome, i think the problem is in your first http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE  you forgot to add '#' before the number on mouseleave

Comment: I've just installed it today :(  yes, but not in this fiddle, and not on the site I'm working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/z8KuE/5/)

You could do this with jquery

### code

```
$('div').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#aaaaaa');
});
$('div').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background','#222222');
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I only modified it to be for a certain class (http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/6/). Since I have a LOT of divs, is it possible to somehow register these events so that all different values for different divs written inside of <div></div> work, regardless of browser and regardless of class?

Comment: @weaponx I didn't get you.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement

Comment: for example, I have 2 divs like these (http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/8/). imagine there are 200 and with a lot more variety in events. How can this be handled to work in Chrome with jquery in the most practical way? (definitely not erasing content from 200 divs and writing jquery with 200 or more lines)

Comment: You have to check the compatibility for each browser, and write code accordingly, there is no easy way for that, you can use browser compatibility checker like in this website  http://www.designer-daily.com/10-cross-browser-compatibility-tools-for-designers-13359 to check the compatability of code with the diffrent browser

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I really didn't expected that such a simple events aren't supported by Chrome, it caught me off guard. Can you write the jquery code for just these 2 divs, so that I can proceed to modify the site?

Comment: ok here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/z8KuE/9/, you could use hover() also which is combination of mouseenter() and mouseleave()

Comment: Thanks, it's great that I don't need to change the content in html. Just one small but very important question - how $('#1').css('left','50px'); can be modified to +50px / -50px (to add / retract the value on current pos)?

Comment: var left1 = parseInt($('#1').css("left"))+50; 
    $('#1').css('left',left1+'px');

Comment: nevermind, found it: $('#1').css('left', '+=50px');  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 50px; top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 150px; background: #222222;" onmouseover="this.style.background='#aaaaaa'" onmouseout="this.style.background='#222222';"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/2/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome only support onmouseover and onmouseout

```
    <div style="position: relative; left: 50px; top: 30px; width: 300px; height: 150px; background: #222222;" 
onmouseenter="this.style.background='#aaaaaa'" 
onmouseleave="this.style.background='#222222';"
onmouseover="this.style.background='#aaaaaa'"
onmouseout="this.style.background='#222222'"

></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8KuE/1/

Comment: I know that, but it would be highly impractical in my case to edit code like that. That's why I need some workaround.